# Div showing on page, shouldn't show unless button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an svg graph with a 100% width and height. I have a filter section that drops down from the top of the screen from being hidden from pressing a button. Recently I have added some sections to the filter section so it has got bigger, unfortunately this means it now partially shows on the main graph, it seems there is deliberate overlap, an effect is created when the filters drop down where it does overlap and this is a wanted effect but not until the button is pressed.

I'm trying to keep the filter section (engagementFilterContainer) out of the screen until the filter section is chosen.

The layout is effectively:

```
<div engagement graph>

<engagement-filter>

<engagementgraph-container>

</div>
```

[image]

What you can see is that there is the engagement-graphSVG which takes up the page, but the engagement-filtercontainer comes down into the graph.

[image]

This is the HTML layout:

```
<div class="Engagement-Graph" id="graph">
  <div class="Engagement-FilterContainer" [ngClass]="{ 'Engagement-FilterContainer--Visible': this.showFilter }">

  </div>
  <div class="Engagement-GraphContainer" [ngClass]="{'Engagement-GraphContainer--WithFilter': this.showFilter}">
    <svg
      class="Engagement-GraphSVG"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1 ">
    </svg>
    <a
      class="Engagement-FeedbackButton"
      href="mailto:toplinksupport@weforum.org">
      {{ 'Send Feedback' | translate }}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see my filter is outside of the graph container which ha the engagement-graphSVG enclosed within it.

The engagement-filtercontainer is not enclosed within the engagement-graphcontainer, when I try and set the position on the SVG It doesnt do anything for me.

CSS:

```
.Engagement-Graph {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
overflow: hidden;

@include tablet() {
  width: 65%;
}
}


.Engagement-FilterContainer {
  overflow: overlay;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: transform $filter-slide-duration;
  transform: translateY(-486px);

  &--Visible {
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
  }

  @include landscape {
    transform: translateY(-436px);
  }
  }


.Engagement-GraphContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  top: 0;
  background-color: $gray-bg-color;
  transition: height $filter-slide-duration, top $filter-slide-duration;

  @include tablet() {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
  }

  svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &--WithFilter {
    height: calc(100% - 480px) !important;
    top: 480px !important;

    @include landscape {
      height: calc(100% - 436px) !important;
      top: 436px !important;
    }
  }
  }
```

I want the filter section to not come into the screen no matter how large it gets, until the button for the filter is pressed.

Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: Your html code is clipped (at the beginning). Also, please put in a code block (ctrl+k)

Comment: I clipped it because it diappeared when It wasn't, I think because of the image

Comment: You are right though, I amended it, have you any thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS. Set `display:none` on your filter box, unless it has the "opened" class:

```
.Engagement-FilterContainer {
   display: none
}

.Engagement-FilterContainer.opened {
    display: block
}
```

Now when the filter section is chosen, you can add the class "opened" to the element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my buttons to show the filter are actually within the filtercontainer and obviously they are also positioned relative to the filter container so that issue still remains, could i just show the buttons anyway and not the filter, and position the buttons statically?

Comment: Trying to show the buttons with display: block; while their container is display: none isnt working